# How to write BLE data on a delayed thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, callback, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a working Android app that writes a list of strings to a low-energy Bluetooth scanner with a delay between each write.  Each item in the list is written in the onCharacteristicWrite() Bluetooth callback then the thread is put to sleep.  The delay is causing the app’s UI thread to be unresponsive.  I tried writing each item in its own thread with the delay but it appears the onCharacteristicWrite() is not run on the delayed thread.  Is there a way to force the BLE writes onto another thread that can be delayed so the UI isn’t affected?

Comment: Hi, do you try this scenario write Service+Async?

Comment: Why are you even inserting delays in the first place? If you really want delays, you should use postDelayed on a handler.

Comment: @Emil Its a display roll on a scanner view port.  Need delay to allow the user to read info.

Comment: @Chinmay, I did not try that.  I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @zappullae In AsyncTask you can perform this background stuff easly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by writing a background thread that peals off each item to send from a list; sends it; delays for the read time and then loops waiting for the send to complete.  onCharacteristicWrite() marks the send as completed and when the background thread picks up the notification it sends the next one.  Works nicely.